# How can I search for posts of mine where the replies and comments from others contain some word?

Tags: support, search

How can I search for   posts of mine where the replies and comments from others contain some word e.g. "namespace"?

When I   search the word with my userid, e.g. `namespace user:156458`,  it only searches for the word in my posts, not in the *replies*  and *comments*  to my posts.

Comment: You can't search comments here.  You can try google.

Comment: How about just replies?

Comment: You could manually search through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156458/tim?tab=responses)

Comment: You can use SEDE if the info is in the datadump https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/707005 finds instances in comments I leave it to you to extend.

Comment: @NathanOliver how do you propose Google would help? Search `site:stackoverflow.com tim namespace`? Seems that might bring back a lot of extra results.

Comment: @MartinSmith I would use `site:stackoverflow.com @tim namespace` which gives 619 results.  IDK if you can sort by date but if you can then that might help even more

Comment: @nathan. What does @ mean?

Comment: @Tim It is part of the reply.  If you look at this comment it starts with `@tim` so searching `@tim` will find comments that reply to tim.

Comment: @NathanOliver the OP has asked 795 questions so TBH they would probably be best off just reviewing each one rather than 619 Google results. There is no guarantee that `@Tim` was used in the comment or not stripped out automatically if it was. And that doesn't help with answers where it would be unlikely to be used.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Stack Exchange Data Explorer for this if you can live with the fact that it is a periodically updated snapshot so doesn't contain the most up-to-date contents.

An example query [is here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/707229/search-pages-i-participated-in-for-text?SearchString=namespace&UserId=156458) that finds all questions you have asked yourself or answered. And then searches the text of

- the question
- all answers
- all comments

for a string. This returns 33 results for your userid and "namespace"